# Spring Boot + MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Создал проект Spring boot с web.
Пытаюсь вывести тестовую страничку. 
Для этого:

1. Написал контроллер
2. Сконфигурировал MVC
3. В каталоге webapp/WEB-INF/view/ создал страницу jsp: index.jsp

Исходный код контроллера:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(name = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Исходный код конфигурации MVC:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Запускаю проект, всё проходит без ошибок. Перехожу на localhost:8080 вылазит ошибка:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

Помогите пожалуйста, целый день не могу побороть ошибку.

Comment: У вас два одинаковых маппинга для `/`, возможно из-за этого что-то внутри спринга ломается. Попробуйте удалить объявление viewController.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Удалил, не помогло.

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю почему, но поменяв аннотацию @Controller на @RestController проблема ушла.

Comment: Между ними разница в дополнительной аннотации ResponseBody у RestController. Т.е. вы должны начать возвращать просто "index" как строку, а не index.jsp

Answer (score 1):

0

При работе Spring Boot + Freemarker если появляется страница:

Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

В версии spring-boot-starter-parent 2.2.1.RELEASE не работает freemarker:

1)переименуйте файлы Freemarker c .ftl на .ftlh
2)Добавьте в application.properties:
spring.freemarker.expose-request-attributes=true

spring.freemarker.suffix= .ftl

Answer (score 0):

ВЫ просто строку возвращаете. String  = index

```
public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
```

Нужно вью возвращать. 
*****\src\main\resources\static\index.html

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = {"/"})
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class HomeController {

    public HomeController() {
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/index", "/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET) //FIXME
    public ModelAndView defaultMethod() {
        System.out.println("home");
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("index.html");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

мне помогло изменение расширения файлов на .ftl